# Passing a list and its value from one class to another thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, class

I am writing a piece of code where I have one class `A` and two threads `B` and `C`.

I create an instance `a` of `A`. I then start both threads, first `B` then `C`.

`B` calls a function `func_name` in `A` by `a.func_name()`. So far so fine.

`C` on the other hand needs to access the result which is a list, say `list_a` defined inside `func_name()` in class `A` and accessed by instance `a`.

I have to match a set of string by using a for loop like this,

```
if self.string_variable in a.list_a:
    print "found"
```

but it gives me an error:

> `A` instance has no attribute `list_a`

Can some one please help me?

Comment: it's better if you post your source code and also the error traceback stack.

Comment: you may need to implement `RLock` over the 'list_a' for mutual sharing b/w the threads.

Comment: This sounds inherently sequential.  What benefit are you getting from threading?  You should probably reanalyze your requirements to better identify which parts of your program (if any) are really conducive to threaded programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need some kind of synchronization primitive – exactly which one depends on further details of your design and requirements.

Assuming the list `a.list_b` is to be created once and is not modified later, thread `C` needs to wait until `a.func_name()` returns.  This can be achieved by adding a `threading.Event` instance to `A`.  In `A.__init__()`, add

```
self.event = threading.Event()
```

At the end of `A.func_name()`, add

```
self.event.set()
```

Before thread `C` tries to access `a.list_b`, add

```
a.event.wait()
```

to wait until `a.func_name()` has finished in thread `B`.

In general, synchronization between threads is a complex topic and an error-prone task.  You should only do this if you really need to.